# Wordpress Custom Options Page is not showing settings fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't get my options page to show any of the added input fields.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'skd_add_admin_menu' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'skd_settings_init' );


function skd_add_admin_menu(  ) { 

    add_menu_page( 'skilte-designer', 'Skilte Designer', 'manage_options', 'skilte-designer', 'skilte-designer/skilte-designer-admin.php', plugins_url( '/skilte-designer/img/sign.png' ), 21  );

}


function skd_settings_init(  ) { 

    register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'skd_settings' );

    add_settings_section(
        'skd_pluginPage_section', 
        __( 'Your section description', 'wordpress' ), 
        'skd_settings_section_callback', 
        'pluginPage'
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'skd_text_field_0', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'wordpress' ), 
        'skd_text_field_0_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'skd_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'skd_text_field_1', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'wordpress' ), 
        'skd_text_field_1_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'skd_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'skd_text_field_2', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'wordpress' ), 
        'skd_text_field_2_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'skd_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'skd_text_field_3', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'wordpress' ), 
        'skd_text_field_3_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'skd_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'skd_text_field_4', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'wordpress' ), 
        'skd_text_field_4_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'skd_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'skd_text_field_5', 
        __( 'Settings field description', 'wordpress' ), 
        'skd_text_field_5_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'skd_pluginPage_section' 
    );


}


function skd_text_field_0_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'skd_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='text' name='skd_settings[skd_text_field_0]' value='<?php echo $options['skd_text_field_0']; ?>'>
    <?php

}


function skd_text_field_1_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'skd_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='text' name='skd_settings[skd_text_field_1]' value='<?php echo $options['skd_text_field_1']; ?>'>
    <?php

}


function skd_text_field_2_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'skd_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='text' name='skd_settings[skd_text_field_2]' value='<?php echo $options['skd_text_field_2']; ?>'>
    <?php

}


function skd_text_field_3_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'skd_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='text' name='skd_settings[skd_text_field_3]' value='<?php echo $options['skd_text_field_3']; ?>'>
    <?php

}


function skd_text_field_4_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'skd_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='text' name='skd_settings[skd_text_field_4]' value='<?php echo $options['skd_text_field_4']; ?>'>
    <?php

}


function skd_text_field_5_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'skd_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='text' name='skd_settings[skd_text_field_5]' value='<?php echo $options['skd_text_field_5']; ?>'>
    <?php

}


function skd_settings_section_callback(  ) { 

    echo __( 'This section description', 'wordpress' );

}


function skd_options_page(  ) { 

    ?>
    <form action='options.php' method='post'>

        <h2>skilte-designer</h2>

        <?php
        settings_fields( 'pluginPage' );
        do_settings_sections( 'pluginPage' );
        submit_button();
        ?>

    </form>
    <?php

}
```

The menu item is created, but none of the settings fields that I try to generate above is showing up on the options page.

I can click on the menu item but the page is then empty.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Read here to make it simple -  http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/10/creating-custom-options-page-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to call the option function in add_action skd_options_page()

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed position  here in add_action( 'admin_menu', 'skd_add_admin_menu' ,13);

Comment: No I missed to call the option function in add_action skd_options_page()